# Hiding all rows whose visible cells are all empty but may have non-empty values in hidden cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to code a VBA macro that hides rows whose visible cells are all empty. This means, that rows whose visible cells are all empty but which also still have hidden cells with non-empty values should be hidden also.

The code I'm using unfortunately hides only rows that have no hidden cells with non-empty values:

```
'==========================================
' Hide Empty Rows
'==========================================
Sub hideEmptyRows()
    ' Set variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lngLastCell As Long
    ' Get last cell
    lngLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    ' Turn screen updating off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Loop from 3rd to last cell
    For i = 3 To lngLastCell
        ' Check if row has any values
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then
            ' Hide row
            Rows(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
    ' turn screen updating on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are already using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)`  to determine the last row, then why not use `Rows(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` as a parameter when calculating `.CountA()` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Wouldn't you want to write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**.SpecialCells() method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) with the [**xlCellTypeVisible**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype) parameter when calculating `.CountA()` like this:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 Then
```